# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

My code works just fine locally but after I published to server I keep getting this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I don't even have a Microsoft.Owin Version 3.0.1.0 in this project, the version used in this project is 2.0.0.0. Then I tried to update the Owin and the dependencies file but to no avail. Even after deleting the Bin folder and rebuild the code I am still having the same issue.

Anybody can help me on this?

EDIT:
After adding this to the Web.Config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This is what I got:

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Project\bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: By publishing to server, do you by any means mean commiting to TFS and this is an actual build error?

Comment: I have just published it (no error) to local, and then copy to server

Comment: Its really hard to figure out this stuff without having access to the project and your server. It might be that one of your reference packages uses a different Owin version, but again, this is hard to remote-debug

Comment: two different versions in different projects in the solution, or different version specified in web.config

Comment: I checked the solution and there is no duplicate ddl of Microsoft.Owin

Answer (score 19):

Verify the installed **Microsoft.Owin** package version [In **Manage Nuget Packages**] with `Web.config  -> Microsoft.Owin` version.

Both these versions **should match**.

This one worked for me

Comment: Package Version was not updated in Web.dev.config automatically. After updating it manually, it is working

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem after updating packages in my solution.  I was able to resolve it by re-installing Microsoft.Owin.

From the Package Manager Console, in Visual Studio: `update-package microsoft.owin`

Upon completion, I was able to run my app again.

Comment: fixed it for me: Update-Package -Id Microsoft.Owin –reinstall

Comment: I got the same error after I published the web app to Azure. My project references Owin 4.0.1. No file or config anywhere in my project references MS Owin 3.0.1. The stranger situation was that, after I updated the package to 4.2.2, Azure gave me an error "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin, Version=4.0.1.0". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue for 4.1.0.0 vs 4.0.1.0 where the error was showing 3.0.1.0 so make sure to check Web.config and set to correct version that is in the .csproj. In my case, I had to update Web.config and replace 4.0.1.0 with 4.1.0.0. The updating package did nothing until the versions matched.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Nuget Package Manager and Update all the packages(If needed) or Update Owin Packages and again build and run the server. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this a few times. Installing the nuget package (and accepting the license) always did the trick for me.

so, rightclick your project in visual studio (?), manage nuget-packages. Look for installed tab, delete if so. Then tab browse, and look for Microsoft.Owin (there are a few), install them and you are ready to go!

Comment: Do u mean reinstall it?

Comment: yes, but only the nuget package. Are you using Visual studio?

Comment: Yes Let me try and let u know the result

Comment: Sorry, did u mean delete Microsoft.Owin from installed tab?

Comment: Unable to uninstall 'Microsoft.Owin 2.0.0' because 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies 2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google 2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount 2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter 2.0.0' depend(s) on it.

Comment: correct, from the installed tab. And then you can reinstall from within the browse tab. If you get notification like xxxx depends on it, de-install that to. Then re-install microsoft.own, you get an question about dependencies, and accept those.

Comment: Hi I noticed that in my Bin file the version of Microsoft.Owin is still 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Go to references and click on Microsoft.Owin to see which version you have installed ,then go web.config and change the reference under Microsoft.Owin to 3.0.1.0 then go to Package.config and to the same.if you don't want any issues.Install the different package versions on Manage Nudget Packages for all of them and repeat the referencing process you did earlier

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after doing zero-downtime patching of SharePoint Subscription Edition from the Feb 2024 CU to the March 2024 CU.

Looks like the patch upgrades the version of Microsoft.Owin from 3.0.1.0 to version 4.2.2.0.

As I was doing zero-downtime patching, I was patching only half the servers at a time.  However, the front-end server that I installed the patch on displayed that error when I attempted to bring it back into the NLB cluster.

This error basically means the version of Microsoft.Owin referenced in the web.config does not match the version that is either in the bin directory or the version installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

I confirmed that the GAC version was 4.2.2.0 by running "dir Microsoft.Owin -recurse" from Powershell starting from c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly.

I navigated to the location of the Microsoft.Owin.dll via Windows Explorer and right click -> Properties and checked the .dll version in the details tab.

Next, I went to the web.config location for one of my web apps.  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories[webapp dir]

Also, compared the web.config on the front end server to the web.config on a dev SharePoint server that I had installed the CU on to verify the CU works.

Ran a search for Microsoft.Owin and found the location where dependent assemblies are defined:
<assemblyBinding..>

I found the dependentAssembly entry for Microsoft.Owin and changed the bindingRedirect to point to version 4.2.2.0 instead of 3.0.1.0.

```
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.2.0" newVersion="4.2.2.0" />
```

Basically, have to do this for each webapp's web.config file.

Then, I was able to bring that front end web server back online in the NLB cluster so I could continue my zero-downtime patching for the other front end web server.

I believe the SharePoint (SP) Products and Configuration wizard will also make this web.config change for you if run after installing the CU.  However, if you are doing zero downtime patching in a server farm, you have to install the patch on all the servers before you can run the SP Products and Configuration wizard.